2x2 complex symmetric eigendecomposition - LAPACK subroutine CLAESY
Asking here because I searched the LAPACK user forums and found nothing.
I have a problem that requires the computation of the eigendecomposition $A=A^T=Q \Lambda Q^T$ for the 2x2 complex symmetric matrix $A$. The LAPACK function CLAESY purports to do this but provides scant documentation, and I'm getting some very confusing results. I cannot get the factors to multiply out to recover $A$ consistently, and the failures seem to correlate with changes in the value of the EVSCAL output parameter of CLAESY.
Below is a Python script I wrote to help debug this problem.
import numpy as np

vhu = np.zeros((2,2),dtype=np.csingle)
vhu[0,0] = -0.740231-0.672353j
vhu[1,0] = 5.96046e-08+1.19209e-07j
vhu[0,1] = 5.96046e-08+1.19209e-07j
vhu[1,1] = -0.223125+0.97479j
print('vhu=',vhu)

# Compute eigendecomposition using standard method and check error
ev, evec = np.linalg.eig(vhu)
print('NumPy eigenvalues =',ev)
print('NumPy eigenvectors =',evec)
print('eig abs error = ',vhu-evec @ np.diag(ev) @ np.transpose(evec))

# Values obtained from CLAESY
cs1 = 0.937786-0.0666464j
sn1 = 0.388443+0.160899j
evscal = 0.937786-0.0666464j
rt1 = -0.740231-0.672353j
rt2 = -0.223125+0.97479j

# Plug CLAESY values into matrices and chug
Q = np.zeros((2,2),dtype=np.csingle)
L = np.zeros((2,2),dtype=np.csingle)
L[0,0] = rt1
L[1,1] = rt2
Q[0,0] = cs
Q[0,1] = -sn
Q[1,0] = sn
Q[1,1] = cs
print('CLAESY Q = ',Q)
print('CLAESY Q^T Q = ',np.transpose(Q) @ Q)

vhu2 = Q @ L @ np.transpose(Q)
print('CLAESY Q*L*Q^T = ',vhu2)

When I run this script, this is the output:
vhu =  [[-7.40231e-01-6.72353e-01j  5.96046e-08+1.19209e-07j]
 [ 5.96046e-08+1.19209e-07j -2.23125e-01+9.74790e-01j]]
NumPy eigenvalues = [-0.740231-0.672353j -0.223125+0.97479j ]
NumPy eigenvectors = [[ 1.000000e+00+0.0000000e+00j  7.622137e-08-1.2257632e-08j]
 [-7.622137e-08+1.2257632e-08j  1.000000e+00+0.0000000e+00j]]
eig abs error =  [[0.0000000e+00+0.j 0.0000000e+00+0.j]
 [3.5527137e-15+0.j 0.0000000e+00+0.j]]
CLAESY Q =  [[ 0.937786-0.0666464j -0.388443-0.160899j ]
 [ 0.388443+0.160899j   0.937786-0.0666464j]]
CLAESY Q^T Q =  [[1.0000004e+00+5.7846137e-08j 1.4949052e-08+0.0000000e+00j]
 [1.4949052e-08+0.0000000e+00j 1.0000004e+00+6.4740973e-08j]]
CLAESY Q*L*Q^T =  [[-0.8814863 -0.4018229j   0.0119791 -0.68231666j]
 [ 0.01197908-0.6823167j  -0.08186992+0.7042599j ]]

Notice that (1) the input matrix is nearly but not quite diagonal, (2) the eigenvalues rt1 and rt2 match those calculated by NumPy, and (3) the eigenvectors are completely different. I suspect this has something to do with the evscal return value because I've noticed that this problem tends to occur when the magnitude of evscal is not close to zero. The LAPACK documentation says only the following:

The complex value by which the eigenvector matrix was scaled to make
it orthonormal. If EVSCAL is zero, the eigenvectors were not computed.
This means one of two things: the 2-by-2 matrix could not be
diagonalized, or the norm of the matrix of eigenvectors before scaling
was larger than the threshold value THRESH (set below).

In the case shown above, EVSCAL is close to 1 and both eigenvalues have magnitudes very close to 1. Scaling Q by EVSCAL produces an interesting matrix with ones on the diagonal and the off-diagonal terms equal to $\pm (0.39999923+i0.20000032)$, but does not yield the correct result. I am totally unsure how to proceed here.

do you get the same results for double precision?

I do not, but interestingly, I have found instances in which the single precision version was correct and the double precision version was incorrect. In such cases, the single-precision EVSCAL value is numerically zero (but not exactly zero) and the double-precision EVSCAL value is close to 1 in magnitude. The single-precision eigenvector matrix is the antidiagonal identity (good because the input matrix was numerically diagonal) and the double-precision eigenvector matrix is not close to an identity matrix.

My input matrix is supposed to be diagonal but in single precision I was finding cases where the off-diagonal elements were several orders of magnitude above machine epsilon. I have reason to seek further diagonalization in this case, hence my interest in CLAESY. But given the difficulty I'm encountering here, I'm now using double precision for calculating the entries of the input matrix, which gives much smaller off-diagonal elements and avoids this problem.

Have you verified that the LAPACK's computed outputs satisfy LAPACK's claimed eigenstatement? (that big text comment right above "Arguments" in claesy.f) .. I ask because it's kind of weirdly stated as XAX^T = L, whereas I normally think of the eigenstatement as AX=XL. The weird/pseudo-orthogonality of these objects should impart some caution when you start moving transposes around, or assuming transposes are inverses, etc. (Hence why I don't like even using the symbol Q).
If the outputs satisfy the claim, then I think you should be able to reconstitute A = inv(X) * L * inv(X^T)?

The matrix $Q$ is indeed orthonormal in the sense $Q^TQ=I$, but $Q^T A Q=Q A Q^T$ fails to diagonalize A. This seems to contravene the documentation, as EVSCAL returned nonzero.

I forgot to mention that in the above comment, inv(Q) = Q^T. This behavior is exhibited in both Intel MKL OneAPI 2023 and AMD AOCL 4.1.0, so it's probably just that my use case is too extreme for the algorithm.
